# Difference between $Var++ and $Var = $Var + [int]1

Tags: excel, powershell, com, active-directory

I have encountered a slightly strange habit of Powershell and would like to understand how this happens.

```
    $CurrentADgroups = (Get-ADGroup -filter * -properties GroupCategory -server $ADSERVER).name
    $Row = [int] 1
    $CurrentADgroups | Foreach {$Sheet2.Cells.Item($Row,1) = $_; $Row++}


Foreach : Exception setting "Item": "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472"
At C:\Script\SCRIPT-2.0.ps1:229 char:28
+         $CurrentADgroups | Foreach {$Sheet2.Cells.Item($Row,1) = $_; $Row++}
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ForEach-Object], SetValueInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterParameterizedPropertySetValueTI,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

This works!:

```
    $CurrentADgroups = (Get-ADGroup -filter * -properties GroupCategory -server $ADSERVER).name
    $Row = [int] 1
    $CurrentADgroups | Foreach {$Sheet2.Cells.Item($Row,1) = $_; $Row = $Row + [int]1}
```

Is it a matter of time? Because in my eyes $Row++ and $Row = $Row + [int]1 do exactly the same thing. They count upwards, one by one.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT1: I changed absolutely nothing besides the $Row between the testing - especially with the AD and the Excelsheet.

Comment: I don't know Powershell, but only difference I see in "traditional" behavior is that `x++` and `x=x+1` return different values (the former returns the value as it was before incrementation, the latter returns the new value).

Comment: Can't see any different values.

Answer (score 1):

### Tests

I tested with this code:

```
foreach ($n in (1..10)) {

    write-host $var
    write-host $var2
    $var++
    $var2 = $var2 + [int]1
    write-host $var
    write-host $var2

    write-host ("-" * 40)
}
```

and if you run it, you can see there is absolutely no difference in behaviour.

You can also use $var.GetType() to see that they are both indeed `Int32`.

I'm not sure if there is a better way to test this...

I would just go with what works for the meantime. Good question though.

---

### Suggestion

Maybe you could break up your code and put in some `write-host` and `$var.gettype()` to test the variables at each stage, so that you can see if there are any differences at all when you run your code in particular.

Comment: I have tried what you said, and there is always exactly the same result. My suggestion is, that maybe the $row++ runs faster (and therefore collapses with the com-object?) than $row = $row + [int]1. But I don't know how to test that.